# I can get the data from another application of the same topic

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have an application for students, but I see that users do not like the idea of re-entering all their information (of agenda and subjects) from scratch, I would like my application to have the option to "get data from X application if it detects that is installed ", just like the browsers Firefox and Chrome when you switch from one to the other they offer to import the history and other data. Some of the target applications allow you to export your SQLite databases and you could start there, but is it possible? is it legal? is it good practice?

If the answer is positive, some recommendation based on your experience?

Comment: `ContentProvider` and `ContentRssolver` with signature permissions for sharing data with apps signed with the same key.

Comment: More elaborate can be done with service and aidl interface. Or just service and messenger. Thought contentProvider is easier to start with. If not enough, go to service with messenger and if still not, jump on aidl. To check if the app is installed, just use the packetManager. And then, dont forget about the permission. You gonna need to undertands the permission and how to bind a service, since API 26 it can be tricky but many topic about that. Not a bad practice, just normal practice for an app to expose data. Of course, you need to be the owner of the 2 app to implement all of this.

Comment: I think you answered what I did not ask, but it is just what I wanted to know, I am not an owner, I would only have wanted to make it easier for potential new users to become familiar with my application, so I will discard that idea, thank you very much